# Redis Cache .Net Client

Tags: .net, redis, server

Does anyone know if Amazon supports C# client libraries for making calls to Redis Server? I know service stack and stack exchange are the only two libraries right now, but Amazon makes no mention of them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either .NET, NodeJS, Ruby, even C/C++ don't require a server component to work with a Redis server. This is why they're *clients*.

It would be required if Amazon would develop an own branch of Redis which would change standard communication protocol defined by official Redis implementation...

Comment: Thanks for giving me the key to why I was confused, "standard communication protocol ". That's my weakest point in the field, the networking and communications aspect. But you gave me a key term to study thanks.

Comment: @DenisCekic No problem. This the point... All Redis clients require to understand Redis protocol :D